# Why does Netbeans Export only to ZIP?

Tags: java, export, netbeans-8

Used to be that when I used Export it would create a JAR file. Now, it offers ONLY Export to ZIP. Consequently, I can't use NetBeans commands need  a JAR.

Might this have something to do with recent installation of the latest WinZip.

Answer (score 0):

Is rare because the option is enabled by default... try this:

```
Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling
```

Comment: Did that. Still, when I click on Export it shows only "to Zip"

Comment: Did you restart the eclipse?

Comment: Actually, I'm using NetBeans. However, it turns out there was no problem. I was not looking in the dist folder where the jar is placed by NB. In a state of dumbness, I was thinking it was a matter of Exporting. I had simply forgotten that's what one uses to Export an NB Project as one would need to do if sending it to another NB developer or the like.